# Area enclosed between two curves (parametric equations)

Tags: calculus, integration, parametric

Someone could help me or explain how to solve this exercise. I understand that the equations are in parametric form but I have not been able to go further and find the enclosed area that they ask me.

I share the statement:

- Find the area enclosed by the curves $x=t-t^2$, $y=1+e^{-t}$ and the $y$-axis.

I would appreciate your help and comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First find where the curve intersects the $y$-axis, by setting $x=0$

We get $t = 0 $ and $t = 1$.

Secondly, the area is given by

$A =  \displaystyle \int x  dy  =  \int_{t=0}^{t=1} x \dfrac{dy}{dt} dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=1} (t - t^2) (- e^{-t} ) dt $

Since we want the positive area, we negate the above expression to obtain

$A = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} (t - t^2) e^{-t}  dt $

Integrating each term by parts, yields,

$A = 3 e^{-1} - 1 $

Comment: You helped me a lot, thank you #GeometryLover